# How to write rich text to word document generated from htm file in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to generate a word doc from saved HTML file using an Open XML library.
If the HTML file does not contain an image I can simply use the code below and write text content to word doc.

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(fileName); //fileName is the Htm file
string Detail = string.Empty;
string webData = string.Empty;
HtmlNode hcollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
Detail = hcollection.InnerText;
```

But if the HTML file contains an embedded image I am struggling to include that image in the word doc.

Using `hcollection.InnerText` only writes the text part and excludes the image.

When I use

```
HtmlNode hcollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
Detail = hcollection.InnerHtml;
```

All the HTML tags get written to the word doc along with path of Image in the  tag

```
<table border='0' width='100%' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' align='center'>
<tr><td valign='top' align="left">
<div style='width:100%'><div id="div_img">
<div>
 <img src="http://www.myweb.com/web/img/2013/07/18/img_1.jpg">
 <span>Sample Text</span></div></div><br><br>Sample Text Content here<br><br>                         </div></td></tr></table>
```

How to remove the html tags and instead of path shown like

```
<img src="http://www.myweb.com/web/img/2013/07/18/img_1.jpg">
```

the corresponding picture gets loaded.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to look at the HTML and translate it to OpenXML somehow.

I've used [HtmlToOpenXml](http://html2openxml.codeplex.com/) open-source library ([license](http://html2openxml.codeplex.com/license)), and that works well enough. It should handle images (inline, local or remote) and correctly insert them into the OpenXML document. I recently submitted a patch which was accepted, so the project is still somewhat active.

There are some limitations with the library though:

> Javascript (<script>), CSS <style>, <meta> and other not supported tags does not generate an error but are **ignored**.

It does handle inline style information, but it entirely ignores other CSS, which was something I needed. I ended up integrating some simple parsing of a single `<style>` element from another open-source project ([jsonfx](http://code.google.com/p/jsonfx/source/browse#svn/trunk/JsonFx/JsonFx.BuildTools/CssCompactor), using [MIT license](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)).

Note: handling multiple `<style>` elements, downloading CSS files, sorting out which style rules have precedence -- these are all problems which I did not address.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the converting of HTML document to MS Word is a very complex task and there are a lot of cases besides of IMAGE tags which need to be solved. The difference between Open XML and HTML formats is absolutely decisive.

If I were you I would look for 3rd party tools for that. It would be chiper to pay for them than spending weeks on investigation and learning of all aspects of the task, writing the code, and then fixing miltiple bugs.

Personaly me used Aspose.Words library for that. It worked perfectly fine, but maybe you want to try another one.

Comment: No, it is not. But again you can try to find another one which is open source.